# Displaying text using variable in label created programatically

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel

I am trying to store a random number in a variable `numberSelected` and display it on a `label created programmatically`.I have the following code

```
 var numberSelected = String()
 let numbers = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]
 numberSelected = numbers.randomElement()!

let label = UILabel()
// Here text is being displayed
label.text = numbers.randomElement()

//Here text is not being displayed
label.text = numberSelected

print(label.text!)
```

How do I display the label using `numberSelected` variable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "This won't work" mean? What happens? Either approach in your example will work.

Comment: This won't work means the text is not being displayed

Comment: I think you should post real code that shows your issue, not an irrelevant example which works fine.

Comment: That's the real code, which I was doing in the playground and the above example doesn't work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple edit:

```
 let numbers = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]
 let numberSelected = numbers.randomElement()!

let label = UILabel()
// This works
label.text = numbers.randomElement()

//This won't work
label.text = numberSelected

print(label.text!)
```

Comment: believe you could also do: `var numberSelected = numbers.randomElement()! `  Issue is that randomElement() returns an element and not a string.

Comment: Ok, That makes sense. Appreciate it.